# How to Read Data continuously from bluetooth device using windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, async-await

A small app where, I had a bluetooth device where it will send continuous data while we do  `await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(data)`
But i unable to read data continuously through windows phone.

```
private async void writeData()
{
    string newLabel = "startReading,RFID\n";
    var data = GetBufferFromByteArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newLabel));
    await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(data);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    readData();
}

private async void readData()
{
    var buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(2048);
    var receivedSize = await _socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 2048, InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead);
    // string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedSize,0,receivedSize.Length);

    var dr = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);

    List<byte> lst = new List<byte>();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { };
    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
    {
        //bytes[i]=dr.ReadByte();
        lst.Add(dr.ReadByte());
    }
    byte[] dataAsBytes = lst.ToArray();
    // byte[] dataAsBytes = lst.SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)).ToArray();
    string s3 = Convert.ToBase64String(dataAsBytes);
    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataAsBytes, 0, 2048);

    Data_txtblcx.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I could probably help you with this but you haven't provided enough information. Where is `_socket` defined and what is it? How are `writeData` and `readData` called? What is the application doing and what are you expecting/trying to get it to do? Consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to simplify your code and see if we can't get it working that way. Here are a couple helpers I threw together for you:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> ReadFromSocket(StreamSocket socket)
{
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var bytesCopied = await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(socket.InputStream, output.AsOutputStream());
        if (bytesCopied > 0)
            return output.ToArray();
    }
    return new byte[0];
}

public static IAsyncOperationWithProgress<uint,uint> WriteToSocket(StreamSocket socket, byte[] bytes)
{
    return socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
}
```

To use them, your example methods would look more like this:

```
private async Task writeData(StreamSocket socket)
{
    await WriteToSocket(socket, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("startReading,RFID\n"));

    await Task.Delay(500);

    await readData(socket);
}

private async Task readData(StreamSocket socket)
{
    byte[] dataAsBytes = await ReadFromSocket(socket);

    Data_txtblcx.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataAsBytes, 0, dataAsBytes.Length > 2048 ? 2048 : dataAsBytes.Length);
}
```

This won't help you if your problem has to do with your handling of the sockets, though.